# How to refresh parent browser window on GridView page change

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I'm using ASP.net; I have a popup browser window that contains an databound gridview with textboxes.  It has an "Add to Order" button which takes the values entered and updates the database, then closes the popup and refreshes the parent.  This currently works perfectly using `window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();self.close();` in a RegisterScriptBlock

I now need to update the database on gridview page chage so that textbox values are not lost.  I put `window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();` into the PageIndexChanging event of the datagrid, but it does not refresh the parent window.  Refreshing the parent window with the order lines helps the user see what they have already ordered.  My update database method runs fine, just not the parent browser refresh. I also tried "window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href" to no avail.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give the code that you write on PageIndexChanging event ?

Comment: Here's the code snippet.  

`Protected Sub grdDisplay_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles grdDisplay.PageIndexChanging
    Dim strScript As New StringBuilder()
    Call addItems()
    grdDisplay.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    Call search()
    strScript.Append("<script language=""JavaScript"">window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();       </script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "RefreshWindow", strScript.ToString)
    End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

In parent aspx page write one JavaScript function

```
 function fnReload() {
        alert('hi')
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
    }

Protected Sub grdDisplay_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles grdDisplay.PageIndexChanging 
    Dim strScript As New StringBuilder() 
    Call addItems() 
    grdDisplay.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex 
    Call search() 
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "reload", "window.opener.fnReload();", true);
End Sub
```

Also insert on alert in `fnReload()` function to check that this function called or not.

Comment: I tried this out, with the Alert() and nothing happens, so for some reason that function is not being called.  Is there another way to inject the Javascript that would work?  I'm not very familiar with Javascript and asp .net beyond the basics.

Comment: Hi could you try this  
strScript.Append("window.opener.fnReload()") 
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType,Me.Page.GetType(), "RefreshWindow", strScript.ToString,True)

Comment: I had to remove one of the GetType parameters due to invalid number of parameters error, but no go as well.  I have this in my Parent page:
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function fnReload() {
            alert("Reload");
            window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
        }  
    </script>

Comment: Hi, I edited answer , please try this. This worked in my sample code.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting somewhere, the function is firing, thanks for your help.  The problem with this though is the page is reloaded to its initial state.  When I use window.opener.document.forms[0].submit(); in the child page on my close button, the parent reloads, but maintains the viewstate from when the user clicked the button to open the child window. I assume I need to call a similar function in the parent to do the postback.  Does it matter if the datagrid (where the items added on the child page are displayed) on the parent is in an ajax updatepanel?

Comment: I don't think so it cause any problem. but you need to check